# How to efficiently transform a list of with entries of form {row_name, column_name, value} to a 2x2 table with the values?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list imported from a CSV file of the form

`data1 = {{row1, column1, value11}, {row2, column1, value21},{row1, column2, value12}, {row2, column2, value22},...,{rowi, columnj, valueij},...}`

where the entries are not necessarily ordered, and the number of entries may be something like 100 to 500.

I would like to transform this to a table like

`data2 == {{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}, ...,{valuei1,...,valueij,...},...}`

where row i has values corresponding to rowi and column j has values corresponding to columnj.

It is trivial to do so manually like this:

```
Selector[idx1_, idx2_] := 
  Select[data1, #[[{1, 2}]] == {idx1, idx2} &][[1, 3]];
data2 = Outer[Selector[#1, #2] &, DeleteDuplicates@data1[[;; , 1]],
   DeleteDuplicates@data1[[;; , 2]]];
```

However, is there perhaps a specialized Mathematica function for this or a better method?

Comment: are `rowi` and `columnj` entries integers?

Comment: @kglr They can be strings or integers in the cases I am working on.

Comment: @Jake how did you `Import` a `"CSV"` file to produce that list in the beginning?

Comment: @CATrevillian Using data1 = Import[InputFile, "Table"]

Comment: @Jake okay, that makes sense, but then where or how did you make the `InputFile`? I have a feeling you may be trying to solve an XY problem, and that this could more easily be solved by different `Import` setting. That said, I’ll post a solution soon to transform the list for use in a `Dataset` with labeled rows and columns.

Comment: @CATrevillian There are several InputFile files, and all of them are results of SQL queries.

Comment: @Jake can you provide an example file? Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a pretty naive attempt, and I wouldn't be surprised to see something more efficient come around, but:

```
Normal[SparseArray[data1 /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y} -> z, Automatic, Missing[]]]
```

Using a mock data set of:

```
data1 = {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 2, 6}, {3, 1, 7}, {3, 2, 8}}
```

The output is:

> {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}

The `Automatic, Missing` portion of `SparseArray` means that any missing data points will be noted as `Missing` in the final result, just as a bit of error checking.

Comment: I would suggest `Missing[]` as default instead, since that way it works with stuff like `DeleteMissing` and `MissingQ`

Comment: Ah, alright. I haven't used `Missing[]` much, so I hadn't read the documentation in as much detail as I perhaps should've. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @eyorble This doesn't work with labeled rows and columns such as `row1` and `column1`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is way to do it using`Dataset`.

Generate sample data:

```
rows = Range[500];
columns = CharacterRange["a", "e"];
data = RandomSample@Flatten[Outer[{#, #2, RandomReal[]} &, rows, columns], 1];
```

Create a dataset and then extract the matrix of values in columns `a` and `b`:

```
groups = GroupBy[data, {Extract[1], Extract[2]}, Extract[{1, 3}]];
ds = Dataset[groups];
ds[
  KeySort /* Values,
  KeySort /* Query[{"a", "b"}] /* Values
  ] // Normal
```

> `{{0.857004, 0.372767}, {0.685266, 0.265005}, {0.523345, 0.752652},
>   ...}`

Answer (score 4):

Oops. Fixed so now it works.

This works if instead of `row1` (or `column1`) you have just `1`.

```
Partition[
  Sort[data1] /. {r_, c_, v_} -> v,     
  Max[ data1[[All, 2]] ]
]
```

So,

```
data1 = {{1, 1, value11}, {2, 1, value21}, {1, 2, value12}, {2, 2, value22}}
```

gives

```
{{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}}
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these are really cool! This one using `GatherBy` seems a might bit simpler, though:

```
Transpose /@ GatherBy[data1, Extract[1]] // Extract[3] /@ # &

(* {{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}} *)
```

Here's another simple syntax method, but this time using `GroupBy`:

```
Values@GroupBy[data1, Extract[1], Extract[3] /@ # &]


(* same as above *)
```

This will transform your list `data1` into a dataset with labeled rows and columns:

```
ds1 = GroupBy[data1, ToString@(Extract[1]@#) &, 
 Association[ToString@(Extract[2]@#) -> Extract[3]@# & /@ #] &];

Dataset[ds1]
```

> [image: Output of above Dataset code]

To extract it from the `Dataset`, we can use an infuriatingly simple syntax when compared with the method shown by C.E.:

```
Normal@Dataset[ds1][Values, Values]


(* same as other methods above *)
```

So, awesome, let's see what method is the most "efficient":

```
(Transpose /@ GatherBy[data1, Extract[1]] // Extract[3] /@ # &) // 
  Trace // Length
(Transpose /@ GatherBy[data1, Extract[1]] // 
   Extract[3] /@ # &) // RepeatedTiming

(* 7 *)
(* {0.000012, {{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}}} *)


(Values@GroupBy[data1, Extract[1], Extract[3] /@ # &]) // 
  Trace // Length
(Values@GroupBy[data1, Extract[1], 
    Extract[3] /@ # &]) // RepeatedTiming

(* 3 *)
(* {8.6*10^-6, {{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}}} *)


(Normal@Dataset[
      GroupBy[data1, ToString@(Extract[1]@#) &, 
       Association[
         ToString@(Extract[2]@#) -> Extract[3]@# & /@ #] &]][Values, 
     Values]) // Trace // Length
(Normal@Dataset[
     GroupBy[data1, ToString@(Extract[1]@#) &, 
      Association[ToString@(Extract[2]@#) -> Extract[3]@# & /@ #] &]][
    Values, Values]) // RepeatedTiming

(* 3 *)
(* {0.0012, {{value11, value12}, {value21, value22}}} *)
```

## Looks like `Values@GroupBy[data1, Extract[1], Extract[3] /@ # &]` is the most expedient!

Thanks for playing :D

Comment: @Jake let me know if I can show any more tricks for this. I'm going to add some timing tests, also.